# Parsing Json Variable into a link

Tags: php, json

I would like to parse a json variable into another link, below is my code.
However, i'v met this error, stating that `"file_get_contents(0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory "`. The directory is working if I type in manually.

```
   <?php
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' +  $movieSeat));
        $counter = count($data);
         echo "<script>movieBTN(x,y){ if (y == 'yes') { alert(x + 'Book Sucessful'); else { alert (x + 'Not sucessful');}</script>";

         for ($x = 0; $x < $counter; $x++) {
              echo  $data[$x]->avail . "<br>" ;
              $avail = $data[$x]->avail;
              echo "<button onclick = movieBTN('".$movieSeat.", ".$avail."')> Movie Seat </button>";
     }

        ?>
```

the `$movieSeat` is gotten from another json.

After I change from `+` to `.`
I have this error `"Undefined offset: 0"` and `"Trying to get property of non-object"`

vardump

```
array(1) { ["avail"]=> string(3) "yes" }
```

Comment: Where do you type it manually? Browser?

Comment: yes, in the browser.. I have also tried it in the code as well, like change the change the link to (http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=1A) . Both works fine. However when I try to get the variable from another json , it doesn't work. Having the error as stated.

Comment: You do realize that browser sends bunch of headers when it sends response to server. And file_get_contents function dies not. My guess those guys defend from bots...

Comment: Use `var_dump($movieSeat);` before `$data = json_decode(...);` and see if you're getting the variable you expect.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: concatenation in PHP is done with a dot `.` not a plus `+`

Answer (score 2):

Concatenation in PHP is done with a dot `.` not a plus `+`

so change this line to

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' . $movieSeat));
// -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  ^
```

Then just use `foreach`:

```
foreach($data as $v) {
    echo  $v['avail'];
}
```

Comment: why do I have error such as
"Undefined offset: 0"  and "trying to get property of non-object"  when I change to .

Comment: Show us a `var_export($data);` please. Edit that into your question

Comment: `string(2) "yes"` makes no sense? `"yes"` is a 3 character string

Comment: Sorry, copied wrongly.  I copied the "no".. I've changed

Comment: I see the edit. A copy/paste of a var_dump is safer than screwing it up

Comment: Show the whole data structure, it matters

Comment: @Abracadaver Thanks I think. Still not sure what data structure he is processing though